# Cortical learning implementation (Numenta's HTM theory)

Tags: algorithm, artificial-intelligence, machine-learning

Has anyone tried to implement Numenta's most recent cortical learning theory (http://www.numenta.com)? I'm working on it and would like to share experience.

Comment: Did you have a specific programming question?

Comment: Well the underlying question was: how would you approach the problem and structure such a program (implementing numenta's technology).

Comment: OK, OK, I understood, next time I'll ask "How to get the length of an array in PHP" and everybody will be so happy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the ideas from Numeta are very promising. But as with any company that wants to make money they are not verbose enough about the technology so that one should be able to re-implement their system (at least from what I have seen so far). It is probably not in their interest that one could just rebuild the system from which they plan to make money.

Also their system is very general and complex. So unless you have a lot of experience with other kinds of neural networks and learning algorithms, I would not recommend experimenting with their ideas. First try to do Backpropagation and maybe some of the less advanced temporal learning until you are really familiar with that.

Comment: Thanks for your answer LiKao ; my question may have been flagged as a bad question by the patrol, but your answer is definitely a good one ! :)

Comment: Don't be too frustrated about this. The complexity of numeta's algorithms is very high and not yet well researched. So do not expect any general answers on this topic. Also stackoverflow is for questions to which an objective answer can be found. "Has anybody done this and can share his/her experience" has no such answer.

Comment: Its very interesting. Most of the current algorithms are basically pattern matching. But it takes into account the temporal changes to learn things.